# With JavaScript how would I increment strings using an array to create a loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to make a web page that has its wallpaper change every time you refresh. I'd like it to display the next image in the array every time the page is refreshed. So every refresh works its way through the list until the end, and then starts over.

Right now I'm using an array and accessing it with a random index, but I need to access it using one that increases by 1 each time, and once I reach the array length I need it to start over again... Right now I'm using this *(which took me forever to figure out)*:

```
$(function background() {
    var images = [
      "wallpaper1.jpg",
      "wallpaper2.jpg",
      "wallpaper3.jpg",
      "wallpaper4.jpg"
    ];
    $("#hero").css({
      "background-image":
        "url(images/wallpapers/" +

        images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] 
        
        + ")"
    });
  });
```

I have found out about incrementing numbers in an array using this:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4];
arr = arr.map(function(val){return ++val;});
console.log(arr);
```

But I can't seem to get the number solution to work with strings. I'm ultra new at all this and I am losing my mind :/

Comment: why don't you use a global variable, then access via that variable. something like: var _imageIdx = 0; var url = images[(++_imageIdx) % images.length]

Comment: You can use `array.forEach` method in this case

Comment: Be clear; do you want to change the wallpaper because your question is confusing about which one you need help

Comment: Are you trying to create something like a slideshow where the wallpaper is changed once every second or two, or trying to add all the wallpapers to the page at once?

Comment: I'm trying to create a page where every time you refresh, the next image in the list is shown as the wallpaper. My apologies for being unclear, and for any slow replies. It takes me some time to dig into and understand solutions. I really appreciate the help however!

Comment: Well that's a new thing, on reload huh? The thing is on reload the array will lose its progress. So the way to do this is a little complex, because to make the progress persistent you might need to use cookies.

Comment: Yeah this does seem to keep getting harder as I go along. I never thought about cookies being required, but it makes sense now that you say it. I'm going to have to start looking into how to set and reference cookies I think.

Comment: @DevinGibson Look into localStorage, a bit easier to work with than cookies.

Comment: I never expected to receive so much help and support on this. Thank you everyone so much for your patience and understanding. @Andy your solution works great, and the inline notes really help to understand what is happening. I just want to hug this entire community. My heart aches with appreciation! I learned much more from this post than I expected!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to save a counter to [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) that you can retrieve on each page load, increment,, make the check, and then save again.

```
$(function () {

    const images = [
      'wallpaper1',
      'wallpaper2',
      'wallpaper3',
      'wallpaper4'
    ];

    // We must check to see if localStorate exists before
    // we do anything
    function hasLocalStorage() {
      try {
        localStorage.setItem('count', 0);
        if (localStorage.getItem('count') === '0') {
          return true;
        }
      } catch(e) {
          return false;
      }
      return false;
    }

    // Fetch the count from localStorage. Because it's
    // saved as a string we need to coerce it to a number
    let count = Number(localStorage.getItem('count'));

    $("#hero").css({
      'background-image': `url(${images[count]})`
    });

    // Increase the count
    count++;

    // If the count is the length of the array (minus one
    // because the array is indexed-based) set the
    // localStorate count to zero, otherwise save the count
    if (count === images.length - 1) {
      localStorage.setItem('count', 0);
    } else {
      localStorage.setItem('count', count);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a helper function to do this:

```
var getNextImage = (() => {
  var i = 0;

  return () => {
    if (i >= images.length)
    {
      i = 0;
    }

    return images[i++];
  };
})();
```

and then replace the `images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)]` call with `getNextImage()`

Like so:

```
$(function background() {
    var images = [
      "wallpaper1.jpg",
      "wallpaper2.jpg",
      "wallpaper3.jpg",
      "wallpaper4.jpg"
    ];

    var getNextImage = (() => {
      var i = 0;
    
      return () => {
        if (i >= images.length)
        {
          i = 0;
        }

        return images[i++];
      };
    })();

    $("#hero").css({
      "background-image":
        "url(images/wallpapers/" + getNextImage() + ")"
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

### Possible, but the persistence is only becuase of the `localStorage`

Hey! Check this out.
This basically selects an image from the array and then changes the background continuously according to the current image. If the last image (when the user last visited the page) was `wallpaper4.jpg`, the next would be automatically the `wallpaper1.jpg`.

> Assuming that the target browser has `localStorage` enabled, this would be the JavaScript code

```js
var images = [
    "wallpaper1.jpg",
    "wallpaper2.jpg",
    "wallpaper3.jpg",
    "wallpaper4.jpg"
    ];

getBgImage = () => {
    var lastImage = localStorage.getItem("wallpaperIdx");
    if (lastImage && images.indexOf(lastImage) < (images.length - 1) && images.indexOf(lastImage) >= 0) {
        localStorage.setItem("wallpaperIdx", images[(images.indexOf(lastImage) + 1)]);
        return images[(images.indexOf(lastImage) + 1)];
    } else if (images.indexOf(lastImage) === (images.length - 1)) {
        localStorage.setItem("wallpaperIdx", images[0]);
        return images[0];
    } else {
        localStorage.setItem("wallpaperIdx", images[0]);
        return images[0];
    }
}

$(function () {
    setInterval(() => {
        var image = getBgImage();
        $('#hero').css({
            "background-image": `url("images/wallpapers/${image}")`,
            "transition": "1s"
        });
    }, 1000)
    clearInterval();
});

$(() => {
    $(window).on("load", () => {
        document.getElementById("hero").style.backgroundImage = `url("images/wallpapers/${image}")`;
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
// Checking if the Local Storage feature is available.
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
  // If it is available, check if there is a value stored by the name 'val'.
  if(localStorage.getItem("val") != null) {
    // If yes increase it by 1.
    localStorage.setItem("val", parseInt(localStorage.getItem("val")) + 1);
  }
  else {
    // If no then create one and set it to 1.
    localStorage.setItem("val", 1);
  }
  // Printing the value on the console and the page to check if it is working (You can remove this later.)
  console.log(localStorage.getItem("val"));
  document.write(localStorage.getItem("val"));

} 
// If it is not available notify the user.
else {
  console.log("Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...");
  document.write("Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...");
}

var num = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("val"));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Local Storage is a feature is in HTML. It can be used to store data in the tab and will be there as long as the tab isn't closed. So, now whenever you reload your page you will get the next number starting from one.